# Extract and reformat text between string/time keys

Tags: linux, bash, logging

I am having problem with extracting text between two strings.

I have log file like this (example data):

```
2018-12-31 09:49:24 addData [data=data]</br>
2018-12-31 09:49:25 publishData .......................
2018-12-31 09:49:26 createDoc [xml=
<mail>
    <recipent>doctor who</recipent>
</mail>]
<attempt>1</attempt>]
2018-12-31 09:49:26 createDoc [xml=
<clientHash>hash</clientHash>
<content>context</content>]
2018-12-31 09:51:27 exampleService [count=1]
```

My code:
`perl -ne 'print if (/09:40/ .. /09:50/)' server.log | sed -n '/createDoc/,/]/p'`

My output is:

```
2018-12-31 09:49:26 createDoc [xml=<mail><recipent>doctor who</recipent>
</mail>]
<attempt>1</attempt>]
2018-12-31 09:49:26 createDoc [xml=
<clientHash>hash</clientHash>
<content>context</content>]
```

but I want to have only xml like this:

```
<element>
<mail><recipent>doctor who</recipent>
</mail>
<attempt>1</attempt>
</element>
<element>
<mail><recipent>doctor who</recipent>
</mail>
<clientHash>hash</clientHash>
<content>context</content>
</element>
```

Comment: Your log file format isn't unambiguous and the time stamps don't seem to exist verbatim in the data you posted. You can probably approximate a proper solution (or even a reliable one, if you can guarantee that the XML data will not contain square brackets ever) but as a first step I would implement time stamp parsing so you can extract times between two time stamps even if those times never occur literally.

Comment: my bad, xml output should not contain "]".

Comment: Is number of `]` **really** odd?

Comment: You're calling perl and then piping that to ***sed***?

Answer (score 0):

I would use Awk for this. If you have GNU Awk, you can even parse the time stamps easily.

```
awk -v start=$(date -d "09:40" +%s) \
    -v end=$(date -d "09:50" +%s) '           
    /^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} / {
        if ($0 ~ / createDoc \[xml=/) {
            split($1, ymd, /-/)
            split($2, hms, /:/)
            when = mktime(ymd[1] " " ymd[2] " " ymd[3] " " hms[1] " " hms[2] " " hms[3])
            p = (when >= start && when <= end)
            if (p) $0 = substr($0, 36)
        }
        else p = 0
    }
    p { sub(/\]$/, ""); print }' file.log
```

This is somewhat Linux-centric -- in addition to GNU Awk (for the [mktime](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) function) the `date` syntax is specific to GNU `date`. (On OSX try `date -j %H:%M:%S 09:40:00 +%s`.)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have **tmp.log** which something like below.

```
2018-12-31 09:49:24 addData [data=data]</br>
2018-12-31 09:49:25 publishData .......................
2018-12-31 09:49:26 createDoc [xml=<mail><recipent>doctor who</recipent></mail>]<attempt>1</attempt>]
2018-12-31 09:49:26 createDoc [xml=<clientHash>hash</clientHash><content>context</content>]
2018-12-31 09:51:27 exampleService [count=1]
```

We can combine some basic commands to get desired output.

- Extract xml contained lines from whole log file.
- Split string according to '[' character and get second element.

`cat tmp.log | grep xml | awk  'BEGIN { FS = "[" } ; { print $2 }'`

This will produce something like that:

```
xml=<mail><recipent>doctor who</recipent></mail><attempt>1</attempt>]
xml=<clientHash>hash</clientHash><content>context</content>]
```

If you also want to get rid of from last character which is '**]**'. Add one more awk too.

```
cat tmp.log | grep xml | awk  'BEGIN { FS = "[" } ; { print $2 }'| awk  'BEGIN { FS = "]" } ; { print $1 }'
```

I know it's not the coolest way to do that, at least it's easy to understand and works.